# Where to get the available icons provided for app development

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

Where to get the available icons for app development.

```
 <Button Content="Button" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,15,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="55"/>
```

Example :  Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}" 
Where to get to see all the available icons with name such as BackButtonStyle and others before using them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new project the VS gives you `StandardStyles.xaml` which is in `Common` folder. There you can find the comented button style like this

```
<!-- 
    Standard AppBarButton Styles for use with Button and ToggleButton

    An AppBarButton Style is provided for each of the glyphs in the Segoe UI Symbol font.  
    Uncomment any style you reference (as not all may be required).
-->

<!--

<Style x:Key="SkipBackAppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="ButtonBase" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="SkipBackAppBarButton"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Skip Back"/>
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE100;"/>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="SkipAheadAppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="ButtonBase" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="SkipAheadAppBarButton"/>
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Skip Ahead"/>
    <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE101;"/>
</Style>
....
....
```

To use these just uncomment it. For more read the [msdn docs here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj841127.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Use [XAML Candy](http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/en-us/app/xaml-candy/8b9e2d69-feed-409c-befb-4ea97f97351a) app for Windows 8.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to your C drive --> Program Files (x86 or not if your OS is 32 bit) --> Microsoft SDKs --> Windows Phone --> v 8.0 --> Icons. They are available for dark and light backgrounds as well as in vector form for editing in Illustrator and such. You can copy and paste the specific ones you want into your project folder and reference them.

Answer (score 1):

These "icons" are actually characters in *Segoe UI Symbol* font. There are multiple ways to see what's available:

- There's a [page on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj841126.aspx) about icons in SegoeUI Symbol and their usage.
- You can open the *Character Map* application in Windows, select this font and browse the characters.
- You can take a look at the `StandardStyles.xaml` file in `Common` folder of Windows Store app templates for Windows 8. You'll find a lot of commented out button styles for `AppBar`, all based on characters from this same font. They can be used in `AppBar` by just uncommenting them, but you can also create a style based on `BackButtonStyle` with a diferent character for the content. Search for `SkipBackAppBarButtonStyle` in the file to find the first one.
- In Windows 8.1 there is [`Symbol`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbol) enumeration for use with [`SymbolIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbolicon) class. It's an improved way for creating [`AppBarButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbarbutton) in Windows 8.1 (there's a sample at the bottom of the last linked page).